# What do I need to fix to get the code to compile?

Tags: java, terminal

Write a Java program with a recursive method that accepts a value i as input and computes the sum:

```
 m(i) = 1/3 + 2/5 + 3/7 + 4/9 + 5/11 + ... + i/(2i + 1)
```

So far I have:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Recursion {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter an i: ");
        int i = sc.nextInt();
        if (i == 0) {
            System.out.println(0);
        }
        else {
            System.out.println(i / (2 * i + 1) + (main(i-1)));
        }
    }
}
```

The code isn't compiling. Please help!!

Comment: *"The code isn't compiling"* The compiler gives you specific error messages when that happens. You should share them.

Comment: Your `main` accepts `String[] args`. You're trying to call it with an `int`. That's why the error is "`Recursion.java`:12: error: incompatible types: `int` cannot be converted to `String[]`".

Comment: Don't use `main` for recursion, create new method.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I think I finally understand what you're trying to do! The problem is you're actually trying to build a string! The method is doing what it should, your return just isn't really doing what it should.

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Recursion
{
    private static String result = null;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter an i: ");
        int i = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println(recursion(i));
    }

    public static String recursion(int i)
    {
        if(i != 0)
        {
            if(result == null)
            {
                result = (i + "/" + (2 * i + 1));
                recursion(i - 1);
            }
            else 
            {
                result = result.concat(" + ").concat(i + "/" + (2 * i + 1));
                recursion(i - 1);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Please let me know if this does what you want it to!

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use recursion on the `main` function. Just create a second function that isn't the `main` and it should work:

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

    public class Recursion {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Enter an i: ");
            int i = sc.nextInt();
            System.out.println(recursion(i));
        }

        public int recursion(int i){
            if (i == 0) {
                return 0;
            }
            else {
                return (i / (2 * i + 1) + (recursion(i-1)));
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure `recursion()` wont return the expected result :-)

Comment: The suggested code above does compile, however, it will always return a 0 :(

Comment: Yes it does because that's what you coded it to do? Due to the way your method ```recursion()``` works it will keep looping itself until ```if (i == 0)``` is true. What were you expecting it to do?

Comment: I intend for `recursion()` to return 0 if the user inputs 0 and the computation if the input !=0

Comment: Still don't quite understand the point of this. Anyway, what you're effectively doing is inputing any integer ```i``` and then continously calling ```recursion()``` on ```i - 1``` until ```i - 1 == 0```, which in turn lets ```if (i == 0)``` return true which leads to the method returning ```0```. Returning ```0``` on any input is exactly what this method has been designed to do.

Comment: Also "I intend for recursion() to return 0 if the user inputs 0 and the computation if the input !=0". If that's what your ```if``` should be checking it should look like ```if ((i == 0) && ((i / (2 * i + 1) + (recursion(i-1))) != 0))```.

Comment: What do I need to fix if say the user inputs `2` and the input goes through `(i / (2 * i + 1) + (recursion(i - 1))` until it reaches 0 and returns 11/15

Comment: This code does not compile

Comment: @heyhooo It does for me. Also OP I think I now understand what you want, I will try to work on something and will answer once I have it.

Comment: it always return the smallest number in condition,

Comment: @Yur how it compile since recursion need to be static?

Comment: the error seems to be integer division

Comment: since 1/2 is zero zro + recursion(i -i) give you the smallest int in your condition

Comment: (i / (2 * i + 1) == 0

Comment: @heyhooo Oh woops, my bad, I just instinctively fixed that warning before trying to compile it lol! If you add static modifier, it does compile though.

Comment: yes, you need to add static, i don't know wh'ats OP is trying to do, can you explain please?

Comment: @heyhooo I think he's trying to build the string at the beginning of his question ```m(i) = 1/3 + 2/5 + 3/7 + 4/9 + 5/11 + ... + i/(2i + 1)```.